# Unable to parse JSON from file using Python3

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get the value of ["pooled_metrics"]["vmaf"]["harmonic_mean"] from a JSON file I want to parse using python. This is the current state of my code:

```
for crf in crf_ranges:
    vmaf_output_crf_list_log = job['config']['output_dir'] + '/' + build_name(stream) + f'/vmaf_{crf}.json'
    # read the vmaf_output_crf_list_log file and get value from ["pooled_metrics"]["vmaf"]["harmonic_mean"]
    with open(vmaf_output_crf_list_log, 'r') as json_vmaf_file:
        # load the json_string["pooled_metrics"] into a python dictionary
        vm = json.loads(json_vmaf_file.read())
        vmaf_values.append((crf, vm["pooled_metrics"]["vmaf"]["harmonic_mean"]))
```

This will give me back the following error:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loads'

I always get back the same AttributeError not matter if I use "load" or  "loads".

I validated the contents of the JSON, which is valid using various online validators, but still, I am not able to load the JSON for further parsing operations.

I expect that I can load a file that contains valid JSON data. The content of the file looks like this:

```
{
  "frames": [
    {
      "frameNum": 0,
      "metrics": {
        "integer_vif_scale2": 0.997330,
      }
    },
  ],
  "pooled_metrics": {
    "vmaf": {
      "min": 89.617207,
      "harmonic_mean": 99.868023
    }
  },
  "aggregate_metrics": {
  }
}
```

Can somebody provide me some advice onto this behavior, what does it seem so absolutely impossible to load this JSON file?

Comment: Are you using Juptyer?  You have used the name `json` for another purpose.  The code you have posted would not fail as you describe.

Comment: Somewhere in previous code you haven't shown you have assigned the variable name `json` to a dictionary, and it no longer represents the `json` module.  Don't do that.

Comment: I don't use Juptyer, never heard of it.

Comment: Then it's the second problem, you used `json` as a variable name. Search your code for `json =`

Comment: BTW, `json.loads(f.read())` can be simplified to just `json.load(f)`

Comment: Your JSON has an incorrect form too.

Comment: @MarkTolonen True, I did, wow, wasn't aware of this. Thanks for this hint. I almost went mad here at the office. Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loads is a method for the json library as the docs say https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads. In this case you are having a `AttributeError` this means that probably you have created another variable named "json" and when you call `json.loads` is calling that variable hence it won't have a loads method.